# groupadd/useradd not found on Mac OSX

Tags: unix, osx-leopard

Does anyone know how to add unix groupadd command on Mac OSX 10.5? I'm trying to do man on groupadd and useradd commands but it doesn't seem to exist.

Answer (score 21):

`groupadd` and `useradd` are Linux-isms.

For some good answers on how to add users from the command line in Mac OS X, see this question on ServerFault:

https://serverfault.com/questions/20702/how-do-i-create-user-accounts-from-the-terminal-in-mac-os-x-10-5

Comment: Please, no link only answers.

Comment: @Masi It's not a link-only answer. OP didn't ask how to add groups from the command line, he asked how to add the groupadd tool itself to OS X, because he mistakenly thought groupadd was something fairly Unix-standard. The answer was, bluntly, "you don't". The link was an attempt to predict and pre-answer something he hadn't yet asked.

Answer (score 5):

Like mentioned before, useradd (and adduser) are Linux commands.

Lucky for you there is the OS X *dscl* command. I've written a simple script for adduser and deluser that you can find at the following links. The key piece of the linked adduser script is below.

https://github.com/GeorgeKA/MiscWork/blob/master/adduser-osx
https://github.com/GeorgeKA/MiscWork/blob/master/deluser-osx

```
sudo dscl . -create /Users/<user>
sudo dscl . -create /Users/<user> UserShell /bin/bash
sudo dscl . -create /Users/<user> RealName "<realName>"
sudo dscl . -create /Users/<user> UniqueID "<userID>"
sudo dscl . -create /Users/<user> PrimaryGroupID <groupID>
sudo dscl . -create /Users/<user> NFSHomeDirectory /Users/<user>
sudo dscl . -passwd /Users/<user> <passwd>
sudo dscl . -append /Groups/admin GroupMembership <user>
```

Answer (score 1):

You might want to check out the third Google [hit](http://osxdaily.com/2007/10/29/how-to-add-a-user-from-the-os-x-command-line-works-with-leopard/) for *"mac useradd equivalent 10.5"*...

Comment: as of now, this page IS the third google hit..

Comment: That's fun... ;)

Comment: Now it is the first.